# Cloud Service like Reverse Proxy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, service, cloud, infrastructure

Anyone can tell me what kind of service fits on this use case below:

I want to expose a public IP that receive HTTPS/HTTP requests and forward the traffic to my services I have in on-prem.

Looking for Azure, AWS, etc, etc, are there some service that serve to my problem?

Regards...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using using Azure and you want HTTPS based request to be sent to your backend APIs (which can be on prem or on any cloud) you can check for **Azure API Management (APIM)**.

You can use the APIM with or without VNET.

APIM can be used in External Mode if you want to integrate a VNET to perform data plane operations which will expose a Public IP as well as a Gateway URL which you can be used to send HTTPS traffic.

**Reference:**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-using-with-vnet?tabs=stv2

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-key-concepts#scenarios

Additionally, you can also check out **Application Gateway**

**Reference:**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/example-scenario/gateway/firewall-application-gateway

Comment: Tks for help! Do you have some type like of solution on cloud provider aws ?

Comment: APIM equivalent in AWS is api-gateway :  https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/api-management/

For Application Gateway in AWS you have : Application Load Balancer : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/introduction.html